# Arduino port relocation (PORTD to PORTB)

Tags: c, arduino, microcontroller, arduino-uno

So I'm trying to connect the chip with an 8-bit data bus. All works good, but...

Arduino Uno uses D0 and D1 for serial TX/RX (USB connection with PC). When I try to open a serial connection (on serial.begin stage) ports D0 and D1 blocks and the chip stops working. This is a problem.

I think I should relocate pins D0 and D1 to another port. But the chip uses 8 pins (8bit chip). So I need to relocate the first pin (D0) and the second pin (D1) to port b. Maybe I can use B4 and B3?

But I don't know how to use PORTD[PD2, PD3, PD4, PD5, PD6, PD7] and PORTB[PB4, PB3] in one time like:

```
var portX = PORTD[PD2, PD3, PD4, PD5, PD6, PD7] + PORTB[PB4, PB3];
portX = data;
```

My code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>     // For I/O and other AVR registers
#include <util/delay.h> // For timing


/* Pinmap (Arduino UNO compatible) */
#define YM_IC (5) // PC5 (= pin A5 for Arduino UNO)
#define YM_CS (4) // PC4 (= pin A4 for Arduino UNO)
#define YM_WR (3) // PC3 (= pin A3 for Arduino UNO)
#define YM_RD (2) // PC2 (= pin A2 for Arduino UNO)
#define YM_A0 (1) // PC1 (= pin A1 for Arduino UNO)
#define YM_A1 (0) // PC0 (= pin A0 for Arduino UNO)
#define YM_CTRL_DDR DDRC
#define YM_CTRL_PORT PORTC
#define YM_DATA_DDR DDRD

#define YD0 (0)(= pin D0 for Arduino UNO)
#define YD1 (1)(= pin D1 for Arduino UNO)
#define YD2 (2)(= pin D2 for Arduino UNO)
#define YD3 (3)(= pin D3 for Arduino UNO)
#define YD4 (4)(= pin D4 for Arduino UNO)
#define YD5 (5)(= pin D5 for Arduino UNO)
#define YD6 (6)(= pin D6 for Arduino UNO)
#define YD7 (7)(= pin D7 for Arduino UNO)

#define YM_DATA_PORT PORTD // Whole PORT D for data bus (= pins D0 to D7 for Arduino UNO)
#define YM_MCLOCK (1) // PB1 = OC1A (= pin D9 for Arduino UNO)
#define YM_MCLOCK_DDR DDRB

extern uint8_t chflash[6];
uint8_t dacflash;
#define NOTEONFLASH 4
#define VGMWAIT 15

static void write_ym(uint8_t data) {
  YM_CTRL_PORT &= ~_BV(YM_CS); // CS LOW
  YM_DATA_PORT = data;
  _delay_us(1);
  YM_CTRL_PORT &= ~_BV(YM_WR); // Write data
  _delay_us(5);
  YM_CTRL_PORT |= _BV(YM_WR);
  _delay_us(5);
  YM_CTRL_PORT |= _BV(YM_CS); // CS HIGH
}

/**
 * Write data into a specific register of the YM2612
 *
 * @author Furrtek
 * @param reg Destination register address
 * @param data Data to write
 */
static void setreg(uint8_t reg, uint8_t data) {
  YM_CTRL_PORT &= ~_BV(YM_A0); // A0 low (select register)
  write_ym(reg);
  YM_CTRL_PORT |= _BV(YM_A0);  // A0 high (write register)
  write_ym(data);
}

void call() {
  setreg(0x28, 0xF0); // Key on
  _delay_ms(1000);
  setreg(0x28, 0x00); // Key off
}

uint8_t getfilebyte() {
  return Serial.read();
}

int main() { 
  init();

  //Serial.begin(9600);
  /* Pins setup */
  YM_CTRL_DDR |= _BV(YM_IC) | _BV(YM_CS) | _BV(YM_WR) | _BV(YM_RD) | _BV(YM_A0) | _BV(YM_A1);
  YM_DATA_DDR |= _BV(YD0) | _BV(YD1) | _BV(YD2) | _BV(YD3) | _BV(YD4) | _BV(YD5) | _BV(YD6) | _BV(YD7); 
  YM_MCLOCK_DDR |= _BV(YM_MCLOCK);
  YM_CTRL_PORT |= _BV(YM_IC) | _BV(YM_CS) | _BV(YM_WR) | _BV(YM_RD); /* IC, CS, WR and RD HIGH by default */
  YM_CTRL_PORT &= ~(_BV(YM_A0) | _BV(YM_A1)); /* A0 and A1 LOW by default */

  /* F_CPU / 2 clock generation */
  TCCR1A = _BV(COM1A0);            /* Toggle OCA1 on compare match */
  TCCR1B = _BV(WGM12) | _BV(CS10); /* CTC mode with prescaler /1 */
  TCCR1C = 0;                      /* Flag reset */
  TCNT1 = 0;                       /* Counter reset */
  OCR1A = 0;                       /* Divide base clock by two */

  /* Reset YM2612 */
  YM_CTRL_PORT &= ~_BV(YM_IC);
  _delay_ms(10);
  YM_CTRL_PORT |= _BV(YM_IC);
  _delay_ms(10);

  /* YM2612 Test code */ 
  setreg(0x22, 0x00); // LFO off
  setreg(0x27, 0x00); // Note off (channel 0)
  setreg(0x28, 0x01); // Note off (channel 1)
  setreg(0x28, 0x02); // Note off (channel 2)
  setreg(0x28, 0x04); // Note off (channel 3)
  setreg(0x28, 0x05); // Note off (channel 4)
  setreg(0x28, 0x06); // Note off (channel 5)
  setreg(0x2B, 0x00); // DAC off
  setreg(0x30, 0x71); //
  setreg(0x34, 0x0D); //
  setreg(0x38, 0x33); //
  setreg(0x3C, 0x01); // DT1/MUL
  setreg(0x40, 0x23); //
  setreg(0x44, 0x2D); //
  setreg(0x48, 0x26); //
  setreg(0x4C, 0x00); // Total level
  setreg(0x50, 0x5F); //
  setreg(0x54, 0x99); //
  setreg(0x58, 0x5F); //
  setreg(0x5C, 0x94); // RS/AR 
  setreg(0x60, 0x05); //
  setreg(0x64, 0x05); //
  setreg(0x68, 0x05); //
  setreg(0x6C, 0x07); // AM/D1R
  setreg(0x70, 0x02); //
  setreg(0x74, 0x02); //
  setreg(0x78, 0x02); //
  setreg(0x7C, 0x02); // D2R
  setreg(0x80, 0x11); //
  setreg(0x84, 0x11); //
  setreg(0x88, 0x11); //
  setreg(0x8C, 0xA6); // D1L/RR
  setreg(0x90, 0x00); //
  setreg(0x94, 0x00); //
  setreg(0x98, 0x00); //
  setreg(0x9C, 0x00); // Proprietary
  setreg(0xB0, 0x32); // Feedback/algorithm
  setreg(0xB4, 0xC0); // Both speakers on
  setreg(0x28, 0x00); // Key off
  setreg(0xA4, 0x22); // 
  setreg(0xA0, 0x69); // Set frequency

  call();

  while(1000) {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
      _delay_ms(1000);
      call();
      _delay_ms(1000);
      char var = getfilebyte();
      Serial.print("Yeah: ");
      Serial.println(var);
    } else {
      Serial.print("Nooo: ");
      Serial.println(Serial.available());
      call();
    }
  }
  while(1);
}
```

Comment: Is this question related to c? I think it should be  onhttps://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: And for Arduino users too, maybe PORTD and PORTB can't be used in one time. I'm not sure that my problem can be in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need bitmath to put them together.  Bitshift and bitwise or and bitwiase and.  Look those up in the reference.  What you want will look something like:

```
byte portX = (PORTD & 0xFC) | ((PORTB >> 3) & 0x03);
```

What you actually end up with might be slightly different though since I am making assumptions about what order you want the bits in.  The first part masks off the high 6 bits of PORTD, the second part shift the two bits you want out of PORTB into the lowest two bits and masks them off.  The | in the middle puts the two together.

Comment: Note that this doesn't mean that the portX variable is somehow connected to those pins.  This just gets the value out into that variable.  You'll have to do this bitmath anytime you want to put anything out on those pins.  The math to do the output is just the reverse of this.  Mask off the two bits for PORTB and or them into PORTB and then mask off the 6 bits from PORTD and write them to PORTD.

Answer (score 0):

A seceond answer because I think you're actually going the other way now that I re-read your question.  I think you want to output to those pins.  You'll need bitmath to do that as well.

Something like:

```
PORTB |= (data & 0x03) << 3;
PORTD |= data & 0xFC;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But first and second code dont works for me "as is". What i shoud change in my code? I place this code snippets to static void  write_ym and comment YM_DATA_PORT = data;

Comment: Upadate: I think i need to write data in this ports. My output is analog sound from chip. i use serial bus for commands writing.

Comment: Did you even read what I wrote?  I told you that I was making assumptions about what order you want the bits in.  Now you want me to fix the order but you're still not going to say anything about what order you want the bits in.  See the problem?

Comment: Not to mention that had you actually read either response and not just tried to copy and paste that code in somewhere you would't have tried both.  IF you had actually read the responses you would see that only one does what you want.  Which one I'm not sure because you haven't made it very clear what you want. But the two do opposite things.  SO had you even read the responses you wouldn't be telling me that you tried both.

Comment: I read your answer. Your second example i shoud use for pins writing. Can you explain please about order? Pins setup on portd?

In original code: YM_DATA_DDR = 0xFF; // Data ports setup

You mean this?

Comment: Order.  What order do you have the bits in your byte.  Which bits do you want to correspond to which pins.  The way I wrote it the high 6 are going on PORTD and the low 2 are going on pins 3 and 4.

Comment: Original example for working with YM2612 don't have order, i think. In original code i don't see structures like:

DDRB = B11111111;
or
DDRD = B11111111;

Can i place here original code or link to repo? It does not contradict the rules of service?

I think i need to clone D pins masks for port B, but i'm not sure.

Comment: The relationship between the pins and the ports is fixed.  You can't move them around.  Perhaps a look at this from the Arduino reference will help you to understand what I'm getting at:  https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PortManipulation

Comment: I already read this, and weatch video on youtube. But i can't reproduce this in my situation. Now i'm trying to make bitmap like:
Step 1:
I think, chip databus shoud be HIGHT (of cource i'm not shure, becouse original example don't use map) So i setting up portD like: DDRD = B11111100;
Step 2:
Now we dont have D0 and D1 and i rebase contacts from pins 0 and 1 to port PB4 and PD5 (12 and 13 port by arduino). So i create mask like: DDRB = B00110001;

But now i listen noice from chip. Before chip dont make any sound after disconnecting ports 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

"There is no way to write to two different registers in the same instruction, so if you need all eight bits to change exactly at the same time you're out of luck." Answer from electronics. Maybe i can test my luck in multiple serial begin and end..